# Electron - dialog.showOpenDialog how to open directory selection dialog box and show "grayed out" files on windows

Tags: javascript, electron

```
ipcMain.on("event", async (event) => {
  const result = await dialog.showOpenDialog(mainWindow, {
    properties: ["openDirectory"],
  });
  event.returnValue = result.filePaths;
});
```

on macOS I see files being grayed out, but on windows I can only see folders.

How can I make it so windows folder selection dialog box shows the files inside the folder I select?

example on mac (files being grayed out):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qP1iv.png

Comment: You can't, it's managed by the OS. On windows items are hidden if they aren't a folder or don't have the target extension, on macos they're grayed out.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a OpenFileDialog

```
 dialog.showOpenDialog({ properties: ['openFile', 'multiSelections'] })
```

As per documentation that can be found here

> electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/dialog

Comment: Could you give an example?

Comment: I have edited my answer with an example

Comment: I dont mean to open a file selection dialog box, I need a folder selection dialog box.

Answer (score 0):

You can open a folder selection dialog box with this:

```
dialog.showOpenDialog({ properties: ['openDirectory'] })
```